# Line break every 3 executions

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a code that replaces in a file all line breaks and sustitute for comma.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var str = fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.replace(/\r\n/g, ','));
});
```

I'm trying to make a version that every 3 executions add a line break.

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: Give an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.replace(/\n/g, ",").replace(/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/g, '$1\n')
```

Or

```
data.replace(/\r\n/g, ",").replace(/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/g, '$1\r\n')
```

Comment: This code is assuming no `","` presents in original `data`, which is very likely untrue.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.replace` can accept a replacer function as second argument, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) here. Using a function fits your case perfectly.

You can create a function that keeps an execution counter in its closure, then conditionally yields a line break on every 3 replacements.

```
function ReplacerFactory() {
  var execCount = 0;

  function replacer() {
    execCount++;
    if (execCount % 3) return ',';
    return '\n';
  }

  return replacer;
}

console.log(data.replace(/\r\n/g, ReplacerFactory()));
```

```js
var data = `a
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
a
lazy
dog
yo!
`;

function ReplacerFactory() {
  var execCount = 0;

  function replacer() {
    execCount++;
    if (execCount % 3) return ',';
    return '\n';
  }

  return replacer;
}

console.log(data.replace(/\n/g, ReplacerFactory()));
```